# How to Use `m2r_parse_relative_links` in m2r2?

Tags: markdown, python-sphinx, relative-path

I have an image in my `README.md` that I would like to be displayed in my sphinx docs (`/docs/readme.rst`). Can someone show me how to use `m2r_parse_relative_links` to make this work?

The `m2r` documentation does not include any information on how to use the `m2r_parse_relative_links` option; it only states one exists. To the best of my knowledge, I believe this option might be set in a `conf.py` as

```
m2r_parse_relative_links = True
```

I have attempted this within my own sphinx documentation and it does not work for me. My project directory structure is:

```
+--project
|  +-- __init__.py
|  +-- index.rst
|  +-- Makefile
|  +-- make.bat
|  +-- readme.rst
|  +-- docs/
|      +-- _build/
|      +-- _statics/
|      +-- _templates/
|      +-- imgs/
|          +-- test.png
|      +-- 
|  +-- src/
|      +-- main.py
|      +-- README.md
```

The `README.md` contains an image

```
![Test](docs/imgs/test.png)
```

`readme.rst` has

```
.. mdinclude:: ./src/README.md
```

and `conf.py` has

```
m2r_parse_relative_links = True
```

Comment: Please show what you have you tried, after you read its documentation: https://pypi.org/project/m2r/

Comment: Configuration of Sphinx is done in `conf.py`, not in `readme.rst`. You do not say if you have configured Sphinx to parse markdown files, if you have installed or configured `m2r`, or if you have built your docs. Please include those details.

Comment: @StevePiercy I made mistakes in my repost. I've corrected these. Sphinx is configured to parse markdown files. `conf.py` includes `source_suffix = {".rst": "restructuredtext", ".md": "markdown"}`

Comment: @StevePiercy Do you know how to get this to work?

Comment: According to https://github.com/crossnox/m2r2#features, `m2r_parse_relative_links` is an "option to parse relative links into ref and doc directives". It says nothing about images.

Comment: @mzjn Can it parse the relative link to an image? For context, see Sphinx GitHub issue #7000 (https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/7000). I don't want to use `myst-parser` because I want to maintain additional restructuredtext I will put in my `readme.rst` file.

Comment: I have not used m2r2 myself. I am just quoting the documentation for that option which I presume refers to `:ref:` and `:doc:` (these are *roles*, not directives, btw).

Comment: What makes you think you cannot maintain reST in a readme.rst file with MyST? You can use both. See https://myst-parser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using/intro.html#enable-myst-in-sphinx

Comment: @StevePiercy Let me put it another way. I simply don't want to use myst. How can I make this work NOT using myst?

Comment: I don't know how to make it work with `m2r2`. I would suggest that you file an issue with the project or contact the maintainers for support.